# Is it possible to specify the size of an icon in DPI or something similar?

Tags: c++, qt, icons

I'm trying to make my icon (which is in a QStandardItem, which does not have a setIconSize() method) bigger. Specifically, I'm trying to make it bigger relative to everything else in my widget.

Like I said there's no convenient setIconSize() method I could use here.

Is there a way to just specify raw DPI that the Icon should take up? I can accommodate it by using size hints of whatever widgets the icons are in, so I just want to make them bigger.

Are there any other ways to do this? Would subclassing offer any new options (can't think of anything but I'm trying to consider everything)?

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using a [`QIcon`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html) to hold the icon?

Comment: Thank you for the response, and I actually am! I create a QPixmap, giving the file path for my .png file in the constructure, and make a QIcon out of that. 

Would using a QIcon somehow let me adjust the size? I was under the impression that this size limitation has something to do with QStandardItem rather than QIcon, because even giving larger images or using the .scaled() function kept my icon size the same in my actual GUI

Comment: @heavyqtuser `QIcon` can hold multiple images with different sizes. So when a Qt component gets a QIcon, it can retrieve the best image for its needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [`QStandardItem::setSizeHint(const QSize &size)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#setSizeHint) to hint the view and delegate about what size you want.

If the result does not please you, then you have to create your own delegate by inheriting from [`QAbstractItemDelegate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html). Then you can draw your icon however you like from within [`QAbstractItemDelegate::paint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#paint).

You will also need to install your delegate in the view widget using one of the 3 functions:

- [`void QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegate(QAbstractItemDelegate *delegate)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate)
- [`void QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegateForColumn(int column, QAbstractItemDelegate *delegate)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForColumn)
- [`void QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegateForRow(int row, QAbstractItemDelegate *delegate)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForRow)